# how to create web player in unity 4.1.3

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to create web player in unity 4.1.3,I searched in Google but I did'nt get any help..please give me  some guidance.

I tried to get in unity forums but , Didn't get any thing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to `File` > `Build Settings...`, upon which you'll get the following window:

[image: unity web player]

You can choose your settings there, and then build it when you're ready.